# CSS/HTML - Issues with Internet Explorer 8 (border-radius, image cover, and padding)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am having issues viewing my site in Internet Explorer.  In the following CSS/HTML the image is supposed to be outlined, curved radius, and scaled to fit. However IE 8 does not scale the image, curve the corners, nor does the outline appear.  Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pave4/  This page is fine in the newest IE (IE8), however I need to make sure it also works on older versions of IE.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="/aboutme/">
    <span class="img-outline"><span class="page-img" id="aboutme"></span></span>
    <span class="page-title">About Me</span>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

​
CSS:

```
.page-title {
      text-align: center;
      display:block;
      text-decoration: none;
}

.img-outline {
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  padding: 5px;

  display: block;   
  margin-left: auto;   
  margin-right: auto;

  -webkit-border-radius: 18%;
  -moz-border-radius: 18%;
  border-radius: 18%;
}

.page-img {
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
  background-size:115px 115px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

  display: block;   
  margin-left: auto;   
  margin-right: auto;

  -webkit-border-radius: 15%;
  -moz-border-radius: 15%;
  border-radius: 15%;
}

li,
li.current,
li.current:visited {
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    width: 118px;
    height: 112px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    opacity: .6;
}

li:hover { opacity: 1; }

li .img-outline {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

li .page-img {
    background-size:70px 70px;
}

li #aboutme {
    background-color: rgb(36, 112, 245);
    background-image: url('http://www.rasnickjewelry.com/images/uploads/900_Animals_300/901_Elephant_Head_Ring_side_R300.jpg');
}
```

​

Comment: Some versions of IE don't support [border-radius](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=border-radius), [background-size](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=background-size) or [colors other than hex notation](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=rgba).

Comment: Do you know why the img-outline is not working either?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using lots of CSS3 attributes that IE8 doesn't support I'm afraid.

Comment: Creating an "incompatible browser" splash page is one way around this limitation.  Most modern browsers allow you to query within whatever backend language you're using for css3 support.  Additionally, you could try to work your way around the border-radius, background-size, and other incompatibilities with images.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment to your original Question, IE up to 8 didn't support rgba colors. Since you don't use the alpha channel, use `background-color: #323232;` instead.

IE8 also doesn't support the standard `opacity` property, you need `filter: alpha(opacity=60);` instead (percantage value sans the %). Related could be that elements in IE require `layout` to render correctly: There is a bunch of articles covering this topic. A good one is [On Having Layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

To get a feel for what css properties and features are supported use resources such as [When Can I Use](http://caniuse.com) or [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do not resize images with styles upload them in the exact size, that will save you loading time.

About the other syles like the border radius try to use this tool http://css3pie.com/

Comment: I use a 70x70 image on the subpages but a 250x250 image on the main page, disregarding IE incompatibility would it be better to use one 250x250 image or a 250x250 image and a 70x70 image?

Comment: Definitely two images, is one of yahoo's best practices to not scale images. [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#no_scale)